# Find out how many days the average temperature is above 22 degrees in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Find out what day the average temperature in August is above 22 degrees.
What should I fix in the code below?

```
> `import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = 'https://github.com/dknife/ML/raw/main/data/'
file = path+'weather.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='CP949')
df.columns = ['date','Average temperature', 'Maximum wind speed', 'Average wind speed']

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")

eight = 8
df.eight = df.query('date.dt.month == @eight')

date = ''
avg = df.eight['Average temperature']

for i in df.eight:
  if avg >= 22.0:
    print('date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = 'https://github.com/dknife/ML/raw/main/data/'
file = path+'weather.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='CP949')
df.columns = ['date','Average temperature', 'Maximum wind speed', 'Average wind speed']

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df2 = df[(df['date'].dt.month == 8) & (df['Average temperature'] > 22.0)]
print(df2)
```